# Angular Material - Error while compiling - 'mat-cell' is not a known element:

Tags: angular, html-table, module, compiler-errors, angular-material-table

Getting the below error.

1. If `mat-cell` is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If `mat-cell` is a Web Component then add **CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA** to the `@NgModule.schemas` of this component to suppress this message.

```
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
imports:[
        MatTableModule
    ]
```

Even after importing the MatTableModule, it throws the error.

Tried importing in both `app.component.ts` and the `xx.component.ts` files

Answer (score 1):

You should import your module at the module level. So at `app.module.ts`

Comment: Hey Wandrille, yes you are right! Thank you for your answer. Since the new angular update doesn’t have the app.module.ts, I created a module for the respective component and imported there and it worked!

Comment: Great, then if fixes your issue, you can validate the answer.